# Is $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lim\limits_{m \rightarrow \infty} |a_n-a_m|=0$ equivalent to $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ being a Cauchy?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

**Are these statements equivalent?**

1. $ (a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} $ is cauchy
2. $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lim\limits_{m \rightarrow \infty} |a_n-a_m|=0$
3. $\lim\limits_{m \rightarrow \infty} \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} |a_n-a_m|=0$

I want to prove it using epsilon delta, but I have great trouble in rewriting the above statements using the epsilon delta definition. Furthermore, I do believe all the statements to be equivalent.

Comment: Are the sequences in $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Every element in the sequence is an element of an arbitrary field $F$ supplied with a norm $|\cdot |$, which is not necessarily complete

Comment: Is the norm real valued? (See the discussion on my answer)

Comment: Yes, like you, robjohn, I only know of norms that take values in the real numbers, so I did not specify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Show that $\boldsymbol{(2)}$ or $\boldsymbol{(3)}$ imply $\boldsymbol{(1)}$**

Choose an $\epsilon\gt0$. We can find an $N$ so that for all $n\ge N$,
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}\left|a_n-a_m\right|\le\epsilon/4
$$
That means that for each $n\ge N$, there is an $M_n$ so that for all $m\ge M_n$,
$$
\left|a_n-a_m\right|\le\epsilon/3
$$
So given $n_1,n_2\ge N$, choose $m_1\ge\max(M_{n_1},N)$ and $m_2\ge\max(M_{m_1},M_{n_2})$
$$
\begin{align}
\left|a_{n_1}-a_{n_2}\right|
&\le\left|a_{n_1}-a_{m_1}\right|+\left|a_{m_1}-a_{m_2}\right|+\left|a_{n_2}-a_{m_2}\right|\\
&\le\epsilon/3+\epsilon/3+\epsilon/3\\
&=\epsilon
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $a_n$ is Cauchy.

---

**Show that $\boldsymbol{(1)}$ implies $\boldsymbol{(2)}$ and $\boldsymbol{(3)}$**

After some discussion, the OP has clarified that the norms they are considering are real-valued.

The other direction is trickier than it appears at first. First, we must show that for each $n$,
$$
\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}|a_n-a_m|\tag{$\ast$}
$$
exists. So, for each $n$, consider the sequence $|a_n-a_m|$. Choose an $\epsilon\gt0$, then find the $N$ so that for all $m_1,m_2\ge N$, we have $|a_{m_1}-a_{m_2}|\le\epsilon$. Then
$$
\big||a_n-a_{m_1}|-|a_n-a_{m_2}|\big|\le|a_{m_1}-a_{m_2}|\le\epsilon
$$
This means that, for each $n$, the sequence $|a_n-a_m|$ is Cauchy and real, hence convergent. Thus, $(\ast)$ exists.

Next, choose any $\epsilon\gt0$. Then we can find an $N$ so that for all $m,n\ge N$, $|a_n-a_m|\le\epsilon$. This means that
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}|a_n-a_m|\le\epsilon\tag{$\ast\ast$}
$$
Since we can choose any $\epsilon\gt0$ and get an $N$ so that if $n\ge N$, we have $(\ast\ast)$, it follows that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty}|a_n-a_m|=0
$$

Comment: I don't believe the other direction follows from the definition of a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: yes. I noticed that as well and have amended my answer.

Comment: The amendment is better. He didn't say so in the question, but in the comments he says he's considering an arbitrary normed field. In which case $|a_n-a_m|$ is _not_ real. In fact the implication does not hold - see my answer.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Ah, so if the norm only takes values in $\mathbb{Q}$, $(\ast)$ may *not* exist.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: I have made a caveat in my answer to this effect.

Comment: However, in [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Definition), a norm takes its values in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: That's a definition of "normed vector space", not "normed field". I'm close to certain that if $F$ is a normed field then $|x|\in F$.

Comment: In [this article](https://www.scribd.com/document/236722727/Normed-Fields), it says the norms are in $\mathbb{R}^\ast$ ($\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are mentioned in particular). A norm on $\mathbb{C}$ must be in $\mathbb{R}$, right?

Comment: To the downvoter: is the downvote due to the topic being discussed with David Ullrich? I have added caveats in my answer noting that I am assuming the norm to be valued in a space that is complete.

Comment: An arbitrary field need not even be ordered, so does $|x| \in F$ make sense? You wouldn't have the triangle inequality or even $|x| \geq 0$. (Or maybe "normed field" by definition requires an ordering?)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: besides the scribd article mentioned above, [this article](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/norm) also says that a norm, in general, whether on an abelian group (including fields) or a vector space is real valued.

Comment: This is exactly the thorough answer I was looking for, thank you for taking the time.

Comment: @Bungo Good point. I'm beginning to suspect that the situation I was recalling was in fact an _ordered_ field, in which we define $|x|$ to be $\pm x$, whichever is positive. The one thing I'm certain of is that I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

Points (2) and (3) are trivially equivalent (just change the roles of $n$ and $m$).

Now, suppose the sequence takes values in a complete space (e.g., $\mathbb{R}$).

**Hint 1**: Suppose $(a_{n})_{n}$ is Cauchy so that it has a limit $a$.
Then,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\left|a_{n}-a_{m}\right| & =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|a_{n}-\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}a_{m}\right| & \text{(by continuity)}\\
 & =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|a_{n}-a\right| & \text{(the sequence has a limit)}
\end{align*}
(try to finish the proof).

**Hint 2**: For the reverse direction, suppose 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\left|a_{n}-a_{m}\right|=0.
$$
Let $\epsilon>0$. Then, by the definition of limit, we can find $N$
such that for all $n\geq N$,
$$
\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\left|a_{n}-a_{m}\right|<\epsilon/2
$$
(try to finish the proof).

Comment: This proves the case for the case that the underlying space is complete. However, I wasn't clear in the question, but I'm interested in the case that the underlying Field is not complete. Just a normed field with the norm $|\cdot |$

Comment: Not sure why I lost a point here. I did specify my answer only held in the case of a complete space.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{a_n\}$ be Cauchy. Then for $\forall \varepsilon>0$, $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$ |a_m-a_n|<\varepsilon, \forall m, n\ge N $$
namely
$$ \lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_m-a_n|=0. \tag{1}$$
Conversely, suppose (1) holds. Then for $\forall \varepsilon>0$, $\exists N_1\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}|a_m-a_n|<\varepsilon/2, \forall m\ge N_1. \tag{2}$$
From (2), $\exists N_2\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$ |a_m-a_n|<\varepsilon, \forall m\ge N_1, \forall n>N_2. $$
Lent $N=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$. Then for above $\varepsilon>0$, one has
$$ |a_m-a_n|<\varepsilon, \forall m, n\ge N. $$
Namely $\{a_n\}$ is Cauchy.

Comment: You're jumping to conclusions where you say "namely" - the inner limit $\lim_n|a_m-a_n|$ need not exist.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, you are right.